# share a variable between computers using dropbox

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a website where users make posts all the posts are stored in a variable i save these variables in local storage and i host the site through dropbox public folder.
Sadly you can only see your posts because there in local storage.
Is there a way i could store that variable in a json file so other users can access it?

E.g.

`var dump = "User post 1"`

user 2 can see user 1's post and when they submit a post

`var dump = "User post 1, User post 2"`

I already have it working with multiple posts but i want to be able to share them on multiple computers

maybe the vars value could be stored in a .json or .txt and when a user posts it adds to that file in dropbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript in the browser does not have the ability to write files, making this idea unfortunately an impossible one. Further complicating things, Dropbox (last I checked) only "serves" static pages, meaning you can't use JavaScript to do an HTTP POST to a Dropbox-hosted file.

Alas, I think the answer is, "No, it can't be done like this".

Comment: oh ok... is there another way to do it though using something else?

Comment: If you are handy with other languages, you can have your users host a locally-installed service. You could then POST to the local service, which might itself have the ability to write a file and then upload it to Dropbox. So, you'd have to write that specialized application and then your users would install it.

Comment: I don't think that would be a option. I might try using meteor.com though its a bit complex but it might be the only way

Comment: I don't know Meteor very well (shame on me!) but if it's writing files and uploading them, it's another full-stack approach. Probably using server-side JavaScript and a hosting application much like Node.js still has to be installed. I don't know that it will be the answer.

Comment: I say the best way to accomplish this is to use a host which supports PHP - don't use Dropbox for this purpose! It may sound like a pain to learn PHP just for this task, but it is the easiest way to get this job done and you won't regret it.

Comment: I agree with tomysshadow -- however, since the author asked about Dropbox I kept it in that scope. Perhaps Dropbox is being used because it's free? Most hosting costs at least a bit of money.